# jQuery .scroll() trigger with window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to trigger a function when the mouse wheel is spun, however the div is the height of the window, therefor isn't scrollable and isn't triggering my function. This is the code I am using to test if it works;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( document ).scroll(function () {
    console.log('it works!');
  });
});
```

You can see the full fiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/8wr8p4ub/1/

If I change the height to an exact value, it triggers, however how can I achieve this when the element isn't scrollable?

Comment: You have to check with mousewheel event here and not document scroll. Since in your case document is not scrolling. Check the answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check with `mousewheel` event here and not document scroll. Since in your case document is not scrolling.

```js
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // scroll up
        console.log("scroll up");
    }
    else {
        // scroll down
        console.log("scroll down");
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hi {
  height: 100vh; // Change to 1200px and see the output in the console.
  width: auto;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for explaining, I understand much better now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother yourself about the scroll once the page content is not so long to bring it out. But from what i saw there, your code is fine, and it will work whenever the content exceeds the minimum page scroll

Better still, you can make use of the mousewheel event in JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mousewheel event handler:

```
$('div').on('mousewheel', function(event){
   if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
     console.log('scrolled up');
   } else {
     console.log('scrolled down');
   }
});
```